# Constructor with default value or two constructors

Tags: c#, oop

What is good practice out of the two ?

a)Constructor with default value ?

```
public DoFoo(string parameter = defaultValue)
```

b)Two constructors instead of default value

```
public DoFoo()

public DoFoo(string parameter) 
: this()
```

Comment: in my opinion the behavior in example b should be inverted. The constructor without parameter should call the one with parameter. Then the behavior would be identical

Comment: @Habib: I am not asking if they are same or different, I know they can treat same but my question is what is good practice? what practice should we have to follow ?

Comment: @user2463514, They both are different and have different behaviour, so as far as best practice is concerned the answer is it depends on the situation. Also asking for best practice is opinion based and would be considered as off topic on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1):

To put my comment to an answer:

The 2 examples you provided are behaving differently.

To have an identical behavior you should do something like:

```
public DoFoo()
  : this("defaultValue")
{
}

public DoFoo(string parameter)
{
  // whatever needs to be done
}
```

I would stick to 2 constructors - just to be clear.

Additionally as pointed out in the link provided by Habib you might get serialization troubles otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Making a default constructor and and making constructor with default parameters are two different things. Which is better, depends upon your particular requirements.